CiviRule: Add a relationship between triggering contakt and data filled in a reference field
I would like to use CiviRule to create a relationship after a contact has been entered in a contact reference field.
The A-side of the relationship should be the contact for which the data was entered and the B-side should be the contact entered in the reference field.
In the screenshots, only the entry option: contact entered in the field


Have I overlooked another option? How can I solve my problem?

As far as I know this is not possible with the current set of triggers, conditions and actions of CiviRules.
You could create a new condition and/or action yourself (or get someone to do it for you).
